# Why can't I delete my answer through the Stack Exchange mobile app?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, android-app, ios-app

Is there a way to delete my own answer through the Stack Exchange mobile app?

Or is it not allowed? And if that is the case, why?

What have I tried: I tried deleting through the Stack Exchange mobile app... I just couldn't find the button or another way.

Why I want it: Sometimes I am away from the desktop, and I find my answer is not what the OP wanted. I wish to delete, but I'm helpless.

Comment: Does the question have multiple answers, or a positively scored answer?

Comment: @Servy i have even tried my answers which have downvotes...there is just no option in the mobile app....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mobile SE apps currently do not support deletion of posts. Kasra Rahjerdi (the lead of SE mobile team) explained the reason in [Allow us to vote to delete from the Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216962): the API lacks in that area.

As a workaround, open the post in a (mobile) browser: there is an option for that under the question.

Comment: Cool thanx!!!! will try the browser way but that way i do not need to use the app at all :)